Resend the last print command in Windows
I use a Windows program to print a sheet via a printer using a button. I want to print two or more copies of this sheet, but the button only works once per time period. How can I resend the last print command?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Some printers have settings for multiple copies.

What program? Does the program have settings or options? Can you check to see if your printer driver has such an option and if that can be set as a default?

Go to Devices and Printers. Right-click the printer and select Printer Properties. Click the Advanced tab and then the Printing Defaults button. In there you will find a setting to change the number of copies. Set that to 2.
